# How to query all tables in dataset and add an identifier?

Tags: google-bigquery

I use this query

```
 SELECT * FROM `project.DATASET.*`
```

to select all the data in DATASET,
There is a way to add a new column to identify which table belong each record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a wildcard query, which support a special `_TABLE_SUFFIX` identifier.  Most use it for filtering the set of matched tables, but you can project it as a result column as well.

More info here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX as src_tbl,
  * 
FROM `project.dataset.*`
```